# What does this Cucumber error message mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I run `cucumber features` and get:

```
Using the default profile...

can't activate builder (~> 2.1.2, runtime) for 
    ["activemodel-3.0.5", "actionpack-3.0.5", "railties-3.0.5"],
already activated builder-3.0.0 for
    ["cucumber-0.10.2"] (Gem::LoadError)
```

What is wrong here and how can I fix it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means you have builder 3.0.0 installed and loaded while rails needs 2.1.x.

Try

`$ gem uninstall builder`

followed by

`$ bundle`

(assuming you're using bundler).

If you're not, do

`$ gem install builder --version "<2.2"`

HTH.

Comment: As scary as this sounded at the time, removing both versions of builder and running bundler again worked.  Thanks.