# Having issues with gem version when running Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, cucumber

I originally posted the question: [What does this Cucumber error message mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684120/what-does-this-cucumber-error-message-mean)

Following the suggestion of uninstalling builder and running bundle worked, for a while.  Now I am getting a similar error, but this time on rack.

When I run `cucumber features` I get the following (previously cucumber has worked):

> can't activate rack (~> 1.2.1,
>   runtime) for ["actionpack-3.0.7",
>   "railties-3.0.7"], already activated
>   rack-1.3.0 for ["rack-test-0.6.0",
>   "cucumber-rails-0.5.0"]
>   (Gem::LoadError)

Deleting rack just to get cucumber to work doesn't sound like a really good idea to me.  How can I fix this problem so it doesn't come back again on another dependency?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could put the exact version numbers for your gems (including Cucumber) in your Gemfile and then run using [bundle exec](http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-exec.1.html)

```
 bundle exec cucumber
```

This will run the Cucumber version in your Gemfile, which should always keep things working even when you upgrade your system version.

The other option is to use RVM [gemsets](http://beginrescueend.com/gemsets/basics/)